# External Drive not mounting Mac (Not Showing Up)

Tags: finder, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk, mount

External SSD not mounting when connected to MacBook Pro. **Not showing on Desktop**, not showing in Finder, **also not showing in Disk Utility**.

I am aware of several fixes e.g.:

- **Finder** > **Settings** > **General** and check `Show these items on desktop:` check `External disks`
- **Finder** > **Settings** > **Sidebar** and check `External disks`

... however the above won't fix the issue on latest macOS (after update), the drive isn't mounted, can't find the external disk and/or container in Disk Utility. One detail: when the SSD is connected, an unreadable *alert window* is showing for a fracture of a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Security related update in macOS Ventura, the OS will not allow new accessories. The *"Allow accessory to connect?"*, *"Do you want to connect ... to this Mac?"* alert will flash and disappear.

### Solution

**System Settings** > **Privacy & Security** > scroll down and find **Allow accessories to connect**.

Default should be `Ask for New Accessories` change it to `Automatically When Unlocked` until this bug is fixed by Apple.

Comment: Is this Mac model specific? On my two Intel Macs, when I search for "allow accessories", I am directed to "Privacy and Security", but there is no "Allow accessories to connect".

Comment: Could be, this is an M1. Let’s see, maybe someone will confirm if it is model specific.

Comment: Aug 1, 2023 this is still Unsolved (Apple M2 2023, Ventura 13.4)

Answer (score 1):

If this happen after ejecting disk without proper unmounting you can fix this by following next steps:

- Go to Activity Monitor
- Quit fsck_exfat (or else if you disk has another file system)
- Go to Activity Monitor
- Run First Aid